# Is there an equivalent to Adobe Illustrator on iPad Pro?

Tags: vector, illustration, ios, ipad

I am using Adobe Illustrator Draw, but it is a very limited app. Is there a professional illustration tool on iPad Pro?

Comment: iPad is a toy, not a computer. That's like asking if there is a good paint program for a video game console. They do exist though, like Mario Paint. But it's not professional, because it's a toy.

Comment: Mmmmmm. Thanks @LateralTerminal, your comment was very useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Affinity Designer has been recently released for iOS and has all the abilities that Adobe Illustrator for desktop has. It is a great app and I definitely recommend downloading it. It is AUD$30 and is worth it as there are no monthly fees attached like Adobe products.

Comment: Thanks Guy. I am using it now and it is very nice!!!

Answer (score 1):

It’s debatable whether any iPad apps are truly “professional” yet, but there are many that come close.

The most Illustrator like app that I have found is Graphic - illustration and design by Indeeo, Inc. https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/graphic-illustration-and-design/id363317633?mt=8
(UK App Store link, hopefully it will redirect you.)

It’s not cheap for an app, but it’s very good.

There are others such and Concepts and ProCreate that are worth looking at, but I would consider all of these as complementary to using Photoshop, Illustrator etc rather than replacements for them. So far.

Comment: Thanks! It looks fjne. I knows already "ProCreate" for drawings, but it is not good for vector graphics.

Comment: Maybe another option is to wait until Serif publish "Affinity Designer" for ipad, like they did with "Affinity Photo"...

Comment: Yes. Affinity Designer is great on the Mac so if/when they do an iPad version it is likely to be a strong contender.

Comment: I hope they improve the iPad version. I miss some tools from his big brother version (like color variable creation)